# Can I set up Postman to reset an environment variable using response data from POST auth call?

Tags: postman

I'm performing some updates to a middleware API and need to frequently test and auth endpoint that requires refresh every 90 seconds. It's a third-party API and I'm not sure there's anyway to manually change the refresh requirement.

As such what I'd like to be able to do is to make a call using postman, and have part of the data from the JSON response, namely "access_token", feed back into an environment variable with the same name. I know it's possible to run test scripts and call a postman method that updates an environment variable. I'm not aware however that this can be linked up with the calling of an endpoint. Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Look into **pre-request scripts**. The script can make POST calls and has access to global or collection env vars. You can then configure your request to first run a pre-request script to POST to your auth API,  parse the response, and set it on an env var.